# Text Area size in asp.net

Tags: c#

Can any tell me what is max size of text area control in asp.net...?
Iam facing problem that this text area only takes 1000 characters my column size is 5000 and in SP that varible size is varchar(2000) still in tables it saves only 1000 characters..
what would be the problem..?

Comment: Is the declaration of your parameter to the stored procedure putting a character limit on what's getting passed to the SP?

Answer (score 0):

There is no maximum size mentioned at [MSDN TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx) or [MSDN TextArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68cs6zxh.aspx). Put a breakpoint in code behind to see whether the application server receives the whole string. If the code behind gets the whole string, then there is a problem between IIS and the DB server. If you don't receive the whole string, make sure the form is submitted through the POST method; supplementary, try a [ViewState chunking](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/ro-RO?query=viewstate%20chunking&ac=8).

Additionally: install smthing like [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and verify the content that is sent from the browser to the server. Fiddler allows you to inspect the communication between the browser and the server.